# How to change order in array ONLY ONCE in unity,monodevelop

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have the array (1,2,3,4,5),and i want to shuffle numbers f.e(4,3,2,1,5),and call shuffle() on starting.
i wrote function but it repeats same numbers not changin order.My code is below;

```
 public void Shuffle()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lists[BrojLevela].Length ; i++)
        {
            int rnd = Random.Range(0, lists[BrojLevela].Length);
            tempGO = lists[BrojLevela][rnd];
            lists[BrojLevela][rnd] = lists[BrojLevela][i];
            lists[BrojLevela][i] = tempGO;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it should work:

```
private IList<int> strList = new List<int>();
void Start()
{
    strList.Add(1);
    strList.Add(2);
    strList.Add(3);
    strList.Add(4);
    strList.Add(5);
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Shuffle(strList);

        foreach(int a in strList)
        {
            Debug.Log(a.ToString());
        }

    }
}

public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
{


    int n = list.Count;
    int rnd = Random.Range(0, n-1);
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rnd;
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Random.Range is a Unity class for generating pseudo-random numbers, but will actually give repeatable results according to some of the documentation, if presented with the same range.
If you change it to use the System.Random class then it works for me.

Just change:

```
int rnd = Random.Range(0, lists[BrojLevela].Length);
```

To:

```
int rnd = new Random().Next(0, lists[BrojLevela].Length);
```

This is the simplest change to make the code sample work as expected, however, it's probably better to create the instance of the Random object outside of the loop and cache it, because creating a new one each time is unnecessary.

Comment: thnx but Next is not cointained in Random

Comment: It's a different Random. Unity has a `UnityEngine.CoreModule.Random`, C# has `System.Random`.
The functionality of the two are different and from your description of intended behaviour, you want `System.Random`. You should be able to use the `System.Random` version if you add a `using System;` at the top of your file

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/486626/how-can-i-shuffle-alist.html

Comment: I just pasted this coede and explained that dont work it gives back (1,2,3,1,3)